# AWS datapipeline import from S3 bucket to a dynamoDB table that is in a different region gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

When I try to use a data-pipeline to import to a dynamo db table that is in the same region as the data pipeline it works without error. When I modify the EMRClusterForLoad step to use a region that is different from the region that the data-pipeline is running in I get the error below.

In my case the Data-pipeline is in eu-west-1 region and dynamodb is in eu-west2 region.

Can anyone explain why this happens and what the solution would be for configuring a data-pipeline to import from an S3 bucket to a dynamo db table that is in a different region than the data-pipeline?

Error:

"Instance type 'm3.xlarge' is not supported in region 'eu-west-2'"

Answer (score 1):

Found the Resolution to the issue here -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-override-instance-type/

Comment: I have the same problem, but can't figure out what are the correct instance types to use. What did you have master/core instance type set to in the end?

Comment: For anyone else I got there in the end with `m4.xlarge` by the time you are reading this, try `m5.xlarge` :-)